Is it safe to provide CVV number by property message in booking.com
I have just canceled one of the booking I did on booking.com. it was still in free cancelation date. but property just sent me a message requesting cvv number for card to get it refunded. never happened in previous cancelation. is it safe to give cvv number to property?

No, it is definitely a scam
Since you're not paying at the property and through Booking, Booking has all the information (because you gave them at booking) to do it.
Provided you used the proper way to cancel (ie. the cancel button on the Booking page and not by a message to the hotel only for ex.) you shouldn't have to do anything. Scams on Booking.com through phishing and hacked accounts are very prevalent.
You may want to report the hotel as their account probably got hacked.

Where did you take from the payment went through booking.com? Regardless, agree that the request for the CVV number is very questionable.

@DavidMulder If they were to pay at the property, there would be no charge at all to refund, especially during the free cancellation period. Some do pre-authorise, but unless charged (which would be fraud without basis), that preauth would fall out automatically. Either way, card info is not to be sent through Booking messages.

There is more than enough countries where you pay before arrival through the hotel. This is for example common in India when you book through Booking.com on many hotel chain properties (In India hotels would often sent you to their own payment portal), but we also encountered it in other places where properties access the card details through Booking.com. Charging for a future service is btw not fraud. And through the booking.com portal I think they can see everything except CVV, so one hotel I think once called us for the CVV  . Point is: lots of international differences.

+1 Since the scam I ran into, booking.com has added a scam warning to messages direct from the property. Heed it.

Unfortunately, one is sometimes supposed to pay using some custom methods and not just in countries like India. Last year I had to fill my card details into some local portal to pay for an appartment in Norway. The link came in an e-mail from the host. It was legit.
